# Does the Model browser of forge viewer support multi byte language?

Tags: autodesk-forge

The model browser appear uncleanaly layout when i set japanese text to it.
Is the Model browser of forge viewer  support multi byte language?

[Model browser with Japanese Text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kfzni.png)

Comment: Can you either set up a live demo (on codepen/jsbin etc) or send the model over to forge.help@autodesk.com (upload to gdrive/wetransfer/dropbox and drop the link over) so we can look into and provide workarounds?

Comment: Thank you Bryan. We are confirming your customer that the data can be provided to Autodesk. I hope you will wait for a while.